# LoadModel does not load in XNA, C# Express Edition

Tags: c#, xna, xna-3.0

I use Windows XP, MSC# 2008 Express Edition, XNA 3.0. I try to load a model in the classic way :

```
model = Content.LoadModel("myModel");
```

In the folder Content I have to files : "myModel.fbx" and "myModel_Texture.png".

When I start with debugging I receive the message:

> Error loading "myModel". File not found

When I start without debugging the message is that the "Game" (name of my program) has encountered a problem and needs to close and asks whether to send or not info to MS.

I try by adding the model to to the ContentManager with "Add existing item". The files exist; I even put the absolute path. I have the same problem.

What to do?

Comment: do you have set `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";` ?